What is the movie called where a woman is exiled because she refuses to stay in virtual simulator?
The plot is basically everyone lives in tiny rooms and spend most of their time in a virtual reality simulator, but a woman gets tired of this and decides she wants to venture to the outside world.
An administrator grants her this wish and has her thrown out into the remant of what the world has become, which is a desert not unlike Mad Max, except the people live underground in the sand and are severly mutated.

Mindwarp has all the elements described. 

A population in virtual reality simulators
The heroine leave the virtual world and goes outside. 
A post-apocalyptic desert covers much of the world.
Underground dwelling mutants

